# Deleting messages in firebase realtime database react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to allow a user on my app to delete one to one messages using firebase realtime database but not sure how to implement this. I thought I could use database().ref(`messages/${key_name}`).remove(); but doing this will remove the messages for both users in the database, even if the other user has not deleted the messages. The other user should be able to still see the messages if they have not deleted on their end.
Do you know how I can achieve this? I have had a look at other links but can't seem to find anything on this. Below is the messages structure:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this is:

Add 2 properties `senderDeleted: false` and `receiverDeleted: false` to each message. If the sender deletes a message, turn `senderDeleted: true`.
If `senderDeleted: true`, do not show the message to the sender. Same for receiverDeleted.

Answer (score 1):

I typically prefer to model my database to closely reflect what the user sees in the app. So if each user can see a different view of the same conversation, I'd consider creating separate conversation copies for each of them. With that data structure, removing the message from one user will not automatically remove it from any other user(s).

This type of data duplication is quite common in NoSQL databases. If you're new to these, I recommend checking out [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).